# Solspace freeform Notifcation member_group setting

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, zoo-visitor

Using Freeform 4.1.2, Zoo Visitor 1.3.28

I'm sending notifications to the user who submits the form. The current_user field here is capturing populated by zoo visitor ({screen_name}). Works great. However, my notifications to the user are only going out to super admins (member_group 1) if they submit the form.If a member from my Members group (member_group 7) submits the form they are not notified. Am I missing a setting somewhere to allow this member group?

```
{exp:freeform:form
form_id="1"
inline_errors="yes"
required="name|email"
notify_user="yes" 
return="referrals/success"
allow_status_edit="yes"
user_email_field="current_user" 
}

<label>Broker: {embed="referrals/current_user"}</label>

<input type="hidden" value="{screen_name}" name="current_user" id="current_user" />


<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $broker_name; ?>" name="broker_name" id="broker_name" />
```

....

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you see a Freeform entry recorded in Freeform when a non Super Admin member group member submits the form? If not, then the issue is likely not just email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
notify_user="yes" 
user_email_field="current_user"
```

...which is good, but your "current_user" hidden field is holding a `{screen_name}` as its value. Shouldn't that be an email address? Eg.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{email}" name="current_user" id="current_user" />
```

Comment: Hi. My {screen_name} is being generated by zoo visitor which contains the email address. However, I changed this variable to {email} and the result is still the same. Only if a super admin submits the form do they get a notification.

Comment: Have you checked that "current_user" is an actual custom field in Freeform? Have you also tried your Freeform form without passing values from ZV (i.e. hard-coded values)?

Comment: Yes, current_user is a custom field and it's being populated each time. When I hard-code the the current_user field, no email is sent to the "user". When I use {email} or {screen_name} and a form submitter from the super-admin group submits the form, the user email is generated.

Comment: Have you tried a simplified version of {exp:freeform:form} on a completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code (no embeds, no js, no other 3rd-party tags, etc), using notify_user="" and user_email_field="" and a hard-coded email address?

Comment: If I remove all php and embeds, it submits as expected. Any thoughts as to why it won't submit when using embeds and PHP?

Comment: It was my php variable causing issues. I found another way to bring that in and it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the `user_notification_template="confirmation_email"` parameter to your form tag in order for the user notifications to be sent.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. I tried that, too. No avail.